# How to deal with Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to ResultSet

Tags: java, netbeans

```
    int v1 = Integer.parseInt(lbl_READING_NUMBER.getText());
    int n = Integer.parseInt(jLabel_CUBIC_METER.getText());

    int x = 0;
    double point = .11;
    double ans = 0;

    if(n<10){

            for(n=0;x<4;x++){
                ans = x*point*100;
            }
        }

    try{
        if(n<10){
            for(n=0;x<4;x++){
                ans = x*point*100;
            }
        }

        String sql ="UPDATE reading set Amount=? where Reading_Number=?";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setDouble(1, ans);
        ps.setInt(2, v1);

        rs =ps.executeUpdate(); //This line gives me error saying: 
           "Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to ResultSet"

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

I want to know what is the cause of this error and how I will fix it. Also this code is my computation of cubic meter in my water bill system

Comment: Have a closer look at your `for` loops. I do not even try to guess, what they are intended to do: as written, they don't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

`executeUpdate` returns an int value which signifies how many rows were updated. Use `executeQuery` to receive a `ResultSet`.

Sample

```
ps.executeUpdate(); // This will update the database and return the number of rows which were affected.
rs = ps.executeQuery("SELECT * etc..."); // This you use when you want to retrieve a ResultSet
```

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

Comment: I already use executeQuery but it gives me sql exception saying: can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: `exceuteQuery` is only for SELECT statements, whilst `executeUpdate` is for data manipulation statements like UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE.

So use `executeUpdate` first, then use `executeQuery` afterwards to retreive the ResultSet. Security ;)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a good indicator of the problem — [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) returns an int value rather than a `ResultSet`

```
int rows = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: how can I implement this to my code sir, this int row. please specify sir.

Comment: That's pretty much it. Why do you think you need a `ResultSet`?

Comment: forgive me for the question sir because im new to netbeans, i just want to know where to insert this int rows to my code above because this is a executeUpdate.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the return type with the one above?